# Are fonts used by a .net application emended in the application?

Tags: vb.net, fonts, uifont

I've downloaded and installed a font in my computer and using it as a font for buttons' texts in my application. I wanted to know if the all the fonts used in an application are automatically embedded in the application when it is built or does it simply link to the fonts installed in the client computer?

Comment: No, you have to carry it with you, as a Resource, either part of your executable or a satellite .dll or single Files or in a archive (a *zipped* file that contains your Fonts). See the [PrivateFontCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection) class.

Comment: It's probably better if you specify what kind of application you're building.

Comment: @Jimi As one of your suggestions I will try to use the 'PrivateFontCollection' class. Thank you for the help.